# gulp-cssimport and gulp-sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm new in a gulp, so I have this issue: I'm building my scss code with gulp-sass and everything was OK before, but now I need to add a third-party CSS file from my 'node_nodules' folder (colorbox.css file) and I've tried to add gulp-cssimport to my gulp-sass task like that:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    scss = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    cssImport = require("gulp-cssimport");

gulp.task('scss', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/[^_]*.?(s)css')
    .pipe(scss({
        includePaths: [
            'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick',
            'node_modules/jquery-colorbox/example1/'
        ]
    }).on('error', scss.logError))
      .pipe(cssImport())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        flexbox: true,
        grid: true,
        browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 5 years', 'Firefox > 20']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/styles'));
});
```

And - no result =( What shall I do to import colorbox.css file into my already builded .css file?

Comment: I do it like https://github.com/link2pk/bootstrap4-gulp-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js I keep one main app.scss file in which I include other scss files. you could also rename to colorbox.css to colorbox.scss and import it on app.scss file.

Comment: @link2pk Thank you for your version but I want to understand how to include third-party css files into my code without renaming =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge both - the compiled scss code and your extra css files (using `gulp-concat` - [more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)) - using `merge-stream` ([more info](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream)). You will need to install both dependencies (`npm install --save-dev gulp-concat-css` and `npm install --save-dev merge-stream`).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    scss = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    merge = require('merge-stream');
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    var sass, css;

    // You scss compiling routine
    sass = gulp.src('./src/scss/**/[^_]*.?(s)css')
        .pipe(scss({
            includePaths: [
                'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick'
            ]
        }).on('error', scss.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            flexbox: true,
            grid: true,
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 5 years', 'Firefox > 20']
        }));

    // Add all the external css files
    css = gulp.src('node_modules/jquery-colorbox/example1/colorbox.css');

    // Merge to styles.css and output to src
    return merge(sass, css)
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/'));

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey! thank you so much for the answer, I've added the code, but nothing has changed =( It's like that now - https://gist.github.com/eisenfox/e333ff6066c6619a93a9d3b18fb0d945

Comment: @NatDavydova why did you used a path reference here: `.pipe(concat('./src/styles/styles.css'))` just use a file name: `styles.css`. Let me know. I think is just that.

Comment: sorry =( updated now! here it is - https://gist.github.com/eisenfox/e333ff6066c6619a93a9d3b18fb0d945 still nothing happens. No errors in console and no result =((

Comment: @NatDavydova no result means no output file generated or no concat?

Comment: oh wow, I see! Now there is an error in console, check please my gist one more time, I've updated it with the last version of my code and the error text. Thank you so much for the help, really!

Comment: @NatDavydova You have several errors and typos. Please use the code i've provided. Check my gist: https://gist.github.com/muecas/cbc78c9cdb60e0a7f7b290099fd12a02

Comment: @NatDavydova did it worked out? Did you checked the gist? You can view the changes as revisions there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is awesome!